# How to say correctly in the past "login" or "logined"?

Tags: grammar, verbs, past-tense, conjugation

A person who perform login to site. This person:

1. "was login" to site
2. "logined" to site

Which version is correct?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The person was **logged in** to the website.

*log in* is a phrasal verb so only the first part of the verb changes when you wish to change the tense. It follows the same rule as *sit down* (*She sat down.*) or *drop out* (*He dropped out of school.*)

See also the [usage note](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/login) for log in on dictionary.com.

Answer (score 3):

`logged-in` would be the perfect term for that.